How to change the state of a variable when launching another composable
I tried many different solutions to solve my problem, but i could not solve it. I would like to change the state of a variable, in a Composable, when another composable is launched. I really tried many different solutions. This is the example code:
@Composable
private fun Actions() {
    Row {
        // More
        var showMore by rememberState(initial = false)

        IconButton(onClick = {showMore = true} ) 
{
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)
            DropdownMenu(expanded = showMore, onDismissRequest = { showMore = false }
            ) {
                Column {
                    Composable1
                    Composable2
                    Composable3
                    Composable4
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

What i need is changing the value of the variable showMore to "false" when the user clicks on one of the Composable in the column. I also tried putting the variable in a viewModel, so to change its value when the user is in the Composable, with a similar code (obviously changing the previous code so to collect the state of the variable from the view model and change it with the two functions):
var showMenuMore by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    fun showMenuMoreOpen() {
        showMenuMore = true
    }

    fun showMenuMoreClose() {
        showMenuMore = false
    }

The problem with this logic is that when i click on the showMore icon on a row, the app opens all the showMore of all the available rows, not only the row that i clicked. I really don't know how to solve this problem.
Thx for your help.
Edit.
I was thinking another thing (without using a view model).
I could change the value of the "var showMore" with a SideEffect (or a LaunchedEffect with Unit as a key) in the composables from 1 to 4, but the variable is not reachable outside its composable (Actions). There is a way to make it reachable?

hoist the state frm child composable to parent and change the state. use lambdas for that

What is showMore there for? In your code, it controls whether the DropDownMenu is shown, but then I don't understand this sentence: The problem with this logic is that when i click on the showMore icon on a row, the app opens all the showMore of all the available rows. So are you trying to use one boolean variable to a) show or hide the primary menu and at the same time use it to 2) show or hide the detail dropdown and at the same time 3) control which detail dropdown should be shown?

@Raghunandan I hosted the state and used the viewModel to change it, but the problem is always the same: it opens all the showMore of all the rows. What do you mean with "use lambdas for that"? thx for your answer.

@BenjyTec. I use the showMore to show the main menu, that lists the various options. So a).

you may need to show more specific to those rows. you have one for all the rows. If each row needs to show or hide menu items you would need state that manages that row's state

@Raghunandan. Ok, but with the previous code the thing works. The app opens only one dialog, not the dialog of all the rows. But with that code i cannot change the state of the variable "showMore" when the user clicks on a composable from 1 to 4. I will continue trying other solutions. Thx for your help.
